# How to update unixODBC via yum on EB awsLinux

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum, rpm, odbc, unixodbc

In summary I need to update unixODBC on the Elastic Beanstalk PHP instances, preferably using yum as it's quite easy to manage via .ebextensions.

- AWS Linux: 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.4.2 running PHP 7.0
- Needed unixODBC: 2.3.1

`sudo yum info unixODBC`

```
Installed Packages
Name        : unixODBC
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.2.14
Release     : 14.7.amzn1
Size        : 1.1 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : amzn-main
Summary     : A complete ODBC driver manager for Linux
URL         : http://www.unixODBC.org/
License     : GPLv2+ and LGPLv2+
Description : Install unixODBC if you want to access databases through ODBC.
            : You will also need the mysql-connector-odbc package if you want to access
            : a MySQL database, and/or the postgresql-odbc package for PostgreSQL.

Available Packages
Name        : unixODBC
Arch        : i686
Version     : 2.2.14
Release     : 14.7.amzn1
Size        : 460 k
Repo        : amzn-main/2017.03
Summary     : A complete ODBC driver manager for Linux
URL         : http://www.unixODBC.org/
License     : GPLv2+ and LGPLv2+
Description : Install unixODBC if you want to access databases through ODBC.
            : You will also need the mysql-connector-odbc package if you want to access
            : a MySQL database, and/or the postgresql-odbc package for PostgreSQL.
```

I found 2 related posts for this here on serverfault but they no longer work. One suggested I disable yum priorities, which I did, but that did not change.

Comment: Amazon Linux package versions are often way out of date. Best option is to switch to Ubuntu if you can. Otherwise you may have to find a third party repository and do some yum priority configuration to go to that repository before the AWS repo.

Answer (score 1):

The `unixODBC` v2.3.1 is available as `unixODBC-utf16`.

Here are the shell commands as a user with sudo access:

```
curl -s https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/prod.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/msprod.repo
sudo yum update
sudo yum info unixODBC*
sudo yum remove unixODBC*
sudo yum install unixODBC-utf16
```

See also: [Install sqlcmd and bcp the SQL Server command-line tools on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools).